# How to mock a service in Angular unit testing?

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-unit-test

I have the following service subscription which is promise

```
getTaskData = async() {
line 1   let response = this.getTaskSV.getTaskData().toPromise();
line 2   this.loading = false;
}
```

I tried like below,

```
   it('should load getTaskData', async () => {
     let getTaskSV= TestBed.inject(getTaskSV);
     spyOn(getTaskSV, 'getTaskData').and.returnValue(of([{name: 'test1'}, {name: 'test2'}]));
     component.getTaskData();
     fixture.detectChanges()
  });
```

When I run the above test case I see the line 1 and 2 are not covered. I am actually new to the test cases. Can any one please help me how to mock this service. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you stop spamming those Teams meetup links?

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a service (an external dependency) and you're mocking it by returning a value every time it is called, of course it won't be covered and this is fine.

To cover those lines, write a separate unit test for `getTaskSV` service.